# Talkback - Customize accessibility text for View Pager swipe

Tags: android, talkback, accessibility

This is driving me nuts and I can't figure out how to just customize the action for "Swipe with two fingers to change page".  I have got it working if I wanted to do some customization after "Double tap", so i'm pretty sure I'm on the right track. But every action type i've tried doesn't seem to work.  Here is what I have to append some text after the "Double tap to".  However, I've tried just about every action enum from AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat and most read out nothing.  I am trying to add some extra text after "Swipe with two fingers to"

```
ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(container, object : AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
        override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host: View, info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat) {
            super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
            // A custom action description. For example, you could use "pause"
            // to have TalkBack speak "double-tap to pause."
            val description = "This is a test"//host.resources.getText(R.string.)
            val customClick = AccessibilityActionCompat(
                AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_CLICK, description
            )
           // for(action in info.actionList){
           //     val t = info.actionList

           //         info.removeAction(action)
          //  }
            info.addAction(customClick)
        }
    })
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar kind of defect like Talkback is announcing while viewpager swipe. I fixed that by setting on **viewpager** oveerride method - onPageScrolled

> override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {
>
> //this will trigger each time when u swipe
> viewpager.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED)
> }

So in your case you can manage custom accessibility text for each Pages in viewpager (Programmatically or in XML) and it will announce once you swipe